# Grouping Standalone Servers in OpServer

Tags: sql-server, grouping, configuration-files, opserver

Is there a way to group standalone servers on the SQL dashboard?  Similarly to being able to split servers into different groups when there are clustered and standalone.

So if I wanted to just put a few servers into a "Production" group together, and then another few into a "Development" group together?